# Disable Checkboxes in Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a loop of checkbox like this one

```
@{
         for (int i = 0; i < Model.Lessons.Count; i++ )
        {
            @Html.Label(Model.Lessons[i].Lesson.Title)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Lessons[i].Lesson.ID)

            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Lessons[i].LessonSelected,new {id = "ddLesson"+i.ToString()})
        }
}
```

Now I want to disable these checkboxes in jquery code until I select one of my title in the dropdownlist. How should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

**HTML/RAZOR**

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Lessons.Count; i++ )
{
    @Html.Label(Model.Lessons[i].Lesson.Title)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Lessons[i].Lesson.ID)

    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Lessons[i].LessonSelected, 
                   new {id = "ddLesson"+i.ToString() @disabled = "disabled" })
}
```

**JS**:

```
$('#dropdownList').change(function() {

    if($(this).val() == 'whatever') {
        $('input[name^=ddLesson]').each(function(i) {
            $("#ddLesson" + i).removeAttr('disabled');
        });
    }

});
```

All checkboxes are disabled on load. The above JS will enable all checkboxes if you select 'whatever' from your dropdown list.

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/X87L6/1/

BUT, if you mean that you will select a value equal to the id of the checkbox that you want to enable:

```
$('#dropdownList').change(function() {
   var id = $(this).val();
   $(id).removeAttr("disabled");

});
```

Comment: It works and All of my checkboxes disabled, but when I select the other dropdownlist it doesn,t enable. How should I change it or what should I add to this code??

Answer (score 0):

If you have these checkboxes with simmilar name, then you may want to use the **StartsWith" property.

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $('.somedropdown').change(function() {

      $('input[name^="ddLesson"]').disabled = true;//This will disable all checkboxes starts with ddLesson. other wise you can use a for loop to disable the checkboxes.

   });


 });  
</script>
```

The startwith jquery link is [Here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Why you need jquery for this? The `CheckBox` helper expects a `boolean` value as second parameter.
 Try like this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Lessons[i].LessonSelected, 
                            new {id = "ddLesson"+i.ToString(), disabled = "disabled"})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[id^="ddLesson"]').prop('disabled', 'disabled');//default set checkbox disable
        $('.somedropdown').change(function () {//on dropdown change
            if ($(this).val() != '0') {
                $('[id^="ddLesson"]').removeAttr('disabled'); //This will enable all checkboxes starts with ddLesson. 

            }
        });


    });
```